# Is "Of...,less than half live in those core English-speaking countries." a appropriate rule for writting?

Tags: grammar, usage

> The English can be under no illusion that the language of the same
> name is exclusively theirs. The small matters of the other nations in
> the British Isles, and of the superpower across the Atlantic, make
> clear that it is joint property. But these countries—along with
> Canada, Australia and other Anglophone peoples—must at some point come
> to terms with the fact that, even collectively, their language no
> longer belongs to them. ***Of the estimated billion people who speak
> English, less than half live in those core English-speaking countries.***

"Of the estimated billion people who speak English" is the essential part for the whole sentence.So,i think,it should be better for "Less than half ***of the estimated billion people who speak English*** live in those core English-speaking countries.".

So,i want to know whether original writting is used to emphasize the "billion people who speak English"? This usage is common?

Comment: Why do you think it's better that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> of the estimated billion people who speak English

This is an adverbial phrase, and there is a lot of flexibility in where adverbial phrases are placed. Generally, we place adverbial phrases at the beginning of a sentence if they are particularly important: this is called [fronting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/fronting). So, yes, it was placed at the beginning of your sentence for emphasis.